# Design help- Design pattern for handling a generic interface for different types of messages

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have to bring up an interface for a node which can receive messages with same header but different message types. The message type comes at a fixed position in the header always. These message types can further be divided into two classifications - Atype(a set of 6 messages) and Btype(a set of 8 messages). The design needs to provide support to add a new message type (eg Ctype) to the interface easily. I have been thinking of writing an interface class which has a std::map with message_type being Atype or Btype and the message_handler_type is a function call to the corresponding message handlers(based on two singleton classes for AtypeMessage and BtypeMessage) - AtypeMessage::get_instance()->AtypeMessageHandler() or BtypeMessage::get_instance()->BtypeMessageHandler() and pass the message along to the corresponding message handler based on the message_type. This node will receive huge amount of traffic.
Will this be a good enough design for future extension? 
Is there any other good design options that I am missing out?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a base class for your messages:

```
class Message {
public:
  virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class MessageA : public Message {
public:
  void do_something() override {
    // ...
  } 
};
```

and inherit all other messages from the base one (like MessageA does in the example). Than you'll be able to use them like

```
void recieve_message(Message&) {
  // ... 
};
```

It also provides a useful method for extension: you can just add another class derived from Message.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood something: the question seemed really messy to me.